# Get enclosing tag of text selenium

Tags: python, selenium

So, I know there's a bunch of ways to obtain an element on a webpage by looking up its tag in selenium, but I was wondering if it was possible to do the reverse. Can I obtain the immediate enclosing tag of some text that I look up on a page using selenium?

Comment: Please provide an example. a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood your question, but try bs4 for this matter.

Comment: Well, I think you can with the help of innerHTML. first get the entire html container then look for your desire text or tag and then you can easily find the _immediate enclosing tag of some text_